# Can't create a very wide canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I'm trying to generate an arbitrary number of rows, where each row contains a label in the left side and a scrolled canvas on the right. My code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super(App, self).__init__(root)
        self.root = root

        # CREATE OUTER FRAMES #

        self.main_frame = MainFrame(root)
        self.main_frame.pack(padx=0, pady=0)

        self.RowCollection = RowCollection(root, self.main_frame)
        self.row_1 = self.RowCollection.row()
        self.row_2 = self.RowCollection.row()
        self.row_3 = self.RowCollection.row()

        def scroll_x(*args):
            # link scrollbar to canvas' xviex
            self.row_1.canvas.xview(*args)
            self.row_2.canvas.xview(*args)
            self.row_3.canvas.xview(*args)

        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.RowCollection.right_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=scroll_x)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=Row.row_count, column=0, sticky='ew')

        canvas_1 = self.row_1.canvas
        canvas_1.config(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        canvas_1.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: canvas_1.configure(scrollregion=canvas_1.bbox('all')))

        canvas_2 = self.row_2.canvas
        canvas_2.config(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        canvas_2.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: canvas_2.configure(scrollregion=canvas_2.bbox('all')))

        canvas_3 = self.row_3.canvas
        canvas_3.config(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        canvas_3.bind('<Configure>', lambda event: canvas_3.configure(scrollregion=canvas_3.bbox('all')))


        # WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000
        WINDOW_HEIGHT = 700
        WINDOW_WIDTH = root.winfo_screenwidth() - 30
        root.geometry(f'{WINDOW_WIDTH}x{WINDOW_HEIGHT}+0+0')
        self.pack(side="top")


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='blue')


class RowCollection:
    """Collection of rows"""

    def __init__(self, root, frame):
        self.row_list = []
        self.root = root
        self.frame = frame
        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame, bg='red', width=10000)
        self.right_frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.left_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)

    def row(self):
        row = Row(self)
        self.row_list.append(row)

        return row

class Row:
    """Every row consists of a label on the left side and a canvas on the right side"""

    row_count = 0
    label_width = 15
    line_weight = 3
    line_yoffset = 3
    padx = 20

    def __init__(self, collection):
        self.frame = collection.frame
        self.root = collection.root
        self.collection = collection
        self.canvas = None
        self.label = None
        self.text = f'Canvas {Row.row_count}'
        self.height = 100

        self.root.update()

        self.label = tk.Label(self.collection.left_frame,
                              text=self.text,
                              height=1,
                              width=Row.label_width,
                              relief='raised')
        self.label.grid(row=Row.row_count, column=0, sticky='ns')

        # configure row size to match future canvas height
        self.collection.left_frame.grid_rowconfigure(Row.row_count, minsize=self.height)

        self.root.update()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.collection.right_frame,
                             width=self.root.winfo_width() - self.label.winfo_width(),
                             height=self.height,
                             bg='white',
                             highlightthickness=0)

        self.canvas.grid(row=Row.row_count, column=0, sticky='ew')

        self.root.update()

        # draw line
        self.line = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.padx,
                                                 self.canvas.winfo_height() - Row.line_yoffset,
                                                 self.canvas.winfo_width() - self.padx,
                                                 self.canvas.winfo_height() - Row.line_yoffset + Row.line_weight,
                                                 fill='#000000', width=0, tags='line')


        # Create point at canvas edge to prevent scrolling from removing padding
        self.bounding_point = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, width=0)
        self.bounding_point = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_width(),
                                                           self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_width(),
                                                           width=0)

        # set column weight to 1 so it expands
        self.collection.right_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # config canvas
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

        Row.row_count += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    
    app = App(root)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

I have created a main frame, with a left and a right frame as children. The left frame contains the labels and the right frame contains the canvases.

I need to have the option to create very wide canvases, but increasing the width option of the right frame seems to have no effect on the canvas size after some value around 3000. What is going on?

Additionally, I would like to have the labels always visible, but, currently, increasing the canvases size eventually pushes the labels outside visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to have the option to create very wide canvases, but increasing the width option of the right frame seems to have no effect on the canvas size after some value around 3000. What is going on?

You are adding the canvas to a frame with `grid`. By default, the frame will grow or shrink to fit the canvas. Therefore, no matter how large you make the frame, it will shrink down to be roughly the size of the canvas (and/or the size of the space in the frames parent, depending on how you added it to the parent).

If you want the canvas to be a specific size, the best thing is to give the canvas that size rather than relying on the width of its containing widget.

If you genuinely want to control the size of the canvas by controlling the size of the frame, you can tell the frame to *not* grow or shrink to fit its children. You do this by turning *geometry propagation* off. This tells the frame to ignore the size of its children. This is rarely the right solution since it often requires more work on your part to make a responsive GUI. Nevertheless, to turn geometry propagation off do this:

```
self.collection.right_frame.grid_propagate(False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also had, for some reason, to move the `grid_columnconfigure` statement to the end of the script, otherwise the size of the scrollbar trough would change as soon as I clicked it. That leaves me with the labels being pushed off issue. Any help with that would also be appreciated.

Comment: By the way,  I didn't want to necessarily control the size of the canvas by controlling the size of the frame. That was poor design on my part.